# Aplicar AJAX post en PHP MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

intento aplicar AJAX post en un programa con patrón MVC, la idea es introducir datos sobre películas desde una vista asíncrona, los datos los voy almacenando en un array de javascript que convierto en string, el código me funciona sin un patrón MVC, es decir, apuntando a un archivo directo, pero con el MVC + el uso del base_url ni siquiera printa un simple var_dump en el método del controlador.

¿En qué estoy fallando para que no me llegue el string al método? ¿la URL es incorrecta?

**Vista**

```
<script>
    
    function envia() {

        //var datos = pelicula.toString();
        var slideStr = JSON.stringify(diapo);
        
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url?>pelicula/guardar',
            data: datos,            
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('exito: '+ datos);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

**Controlador**

```
<?php

    require_once 'models/pelicula.php';

    public function guardar($datos){

        if(isset($_POST)){

            $decoded = json_decode($datos);  

            $pelicula = new Pelicula();
            $pelicula->setGenero($decoded[0]);
            $pelicula->setTitulo($decoded[1]);
            $pelicula->setDescripcion($decoded[2]);

            $save = $pelicula->guardar();
        }
        header("Location:".base_url);
    }

?>
```

**Modelo (simplificado)**

```
<?php

    public $id;
    public $genero;
    public $titulo;
    public $descripcion;

    public function guardar(){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO peliculas VALUES(null,{$this->getGenero()},{$this->getTitulo()},'{$this->getDescripcion()}')";        
    
        $save = $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = false;
        if($save){
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }   

?>
```

Un saludo y gracias :)

Comment: de dónde sale la variable `base_url` en qué momento la declaras? y por qué sin `$`?

Comment: `base_url` es una "constante" o "alias" para definir la raíz del proyecto (sea local o server) es decir tendría el valor de `http://localhost/peliculas/`

Comment: Pero en algún momento la tienes que definir. podrías poner el código donde la defines

Comment: Está en un archivo de configuración     `<?php
define("base_url", "http://localhost/peliculas/");
define("controller_default", "usuarioController");
define("action_default", "index");
?>`

Comment: El problema es tu MVC es nativo, pero no tiene un dispatcher, el dispatcher se encarga de routear la url al controlador adecuado. Te dejo más info. https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/3334136

Comment: Te agradezco el enlace, voy a mirarlo con detenimiento, una cosa si debo decir aunque no sé si tiene relación con tu aporte, cuando hago CRUD de usuarios, solo uso PHP, sin eventos JS y no he tenido problemas con las rutas entre vista/controladores.